# Is there a pre built compiled version of ffmpeg for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I am struggling in compiling ffmpeg with no success. Is there any ready for use, pre compiled libraries for the iphone?

In general, what I need is to stream a radio station in mms wmv format, is there any other solution?

Thanks
Meir

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use mms ?
IOS support Http live streaming very well .

Comment: Do you want to support live streaming？

Comment: I do not use mms, this is the way the radio station that I wand to use are using. Yes, I need audio live streaming. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded, but it's not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

You may have to play with our code a bit to get wmv format, but we do support rtsp, and I know a couple devs that got this to work with mms.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find some documentation for this project?